# How to remove these syntax errors in php?

Tags: php, syntax-error

I want to remove syntax error from a php script file. After hour of checking i could not remove them, How could be these identified?

1st one is `Parse error: syntax error, unexpected ')'` on second line of below code:

```
require( "./sources/misc/classes.php" );
    ( );
    if ( file_exists( "./sources/sql/sql.php" ) )
    {
        require( "./sources/sql/sql.php" );
    }
    else
    {
        header( "Location: install/" );
    }
```

And also it gives error on line on as `Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '['` on first line of below code:

```
if ( [$FORM['ajax']]isset( $FORM['ajax'], $aj ) )
{
    require( "./sources/{$FORM['ajax']}.php" );
    ( );
    $base->$FORM['x']( );
}
```

Will you help me identify and understand errors? and Why they come?

Comment: Q: Why do you have `( );`???  If you delete it, does it fix the problem?  Q: Why not simply `if (isset($FORM['ajax]) { ... }`???

Comment: The error messages point to the exact lines of code with the errors. Isn't it obvious what's wrong with them? What do you expect those lines to do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

remove those lines of code with ....

```
( );
```

AND

```
if ( [$FORM['ajax']]isset( $FORM['ajax'], $aj ) )
```

should be

```
if (isset( $FORM['ajax'], $aj ) )
```

... and this is dangerous, never trust user input ... here: user might include files you don't want to be included!

```
require( "./sources/{$FORM['ajax']}.php" );
```

Comment: Where does this code come from ... you did not write that on your own!?

Comment: Great. You solved my headache. I was able to remove ():, but could not the second one.

Comment: If you could not change the second one, the source you gave us is not like you have shown to us ... but I can't estimate what else the "if logic" should be then.

Comment: Yeah, I am the master himself ... you can even write me an email at gMail ;)

Comment: the.master.himself ... ;) @gmail.com

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/37019/discussion-between-sanam-mirza-and-djot)

Comment: Do you wrap all your strings in brackets for the fun? (require is not a function call)

Comment: Who, me? Look at the original ... I can't remember the code being like this. I did'n provide a perfect code solution, only few suggestions. Who cares anyway!? Morons all over here ...

Answer (score 0):

PHP does not like empty expressions like `();`

Remove that and you should be fine.

Answer (score 0):

First one..

```
require( "./sources/misc/classes.php" );
    //( );
    if ( file_exists( "./sources/sql/sql.php" ) )
    {
        require( "./sources/sql/sql.php" );
    }
    else
    {
        header( "Location: install/" );
    }
```

second

```
if (isset($FORM['ajax'], $aj))
{
    require( "./sources/" . $FORM['ajax'] . ".php" );
    //( );
    $base->$FORM['x'];//( );
}
```